# VsTest task on Azure Pipelines only running one test method out of two?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a project solution where I have my application and a UnitTest.cs with two void test methods. In Visual Studios, I am able to use Test Explorer to run the test project and I see that the two test methods pass successfully. However, trying to automate this in Azure Pipelines using the VsTest task only results in one of the test methods executing and no sign that the second one was ever run. This does not result in any error and the build becomes successful but I want the other test to run so that when we are ready to implement said tests, we can be sure that the pipeline will automate the process correctly.

My YAML code for the test task in the pipeline is as follows:

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\UnitTest.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Please check that your files exists in places you expect. For this purpose you can list files using `bash` task.

Comment: Just checked and the UnitTest.dll is in the path that I expected it to be in. I just modified the VsTest task to explicitly use the specified path with no wild card and still it is only running only one test out of the two i had made. I double checked my repository and the latest code with the two tests was committed and in the repo.

Comment: Can add your tests to question?

Comment: I failed to reproduce above issue. Could you share the the log of Vstest task too?